# Distance between tree levels

Tags: tikz-trees

Please, I will like to adjust the distance between tree levels as shown in the figure. Is there a way of varying the separation?
Thank you.
Best regards.

[image]

The actual code that I will like to edit is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{
        my node style/.style={
            font=\small,
            top color=white,
            bottom color=blue!25,
            rectangle,
            rounded corners,
            minimum size=6mm,
            draw=blue!75,
            very thick,
            drop shadow,
            align=center,
        }
    }
    \forestset{
        my tree style/.style={
            for tree={
                parent anchor=south,
                child anchor=north,
                l sep+=5pt,
                my node style,
                edge={draw=blue!50, thick},
                edge path={
                    \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-7.5pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
                },
                if n children=3{
                    for children={
                        if n=2{calign with current}{}
                    }
                }{},
                delay={if content={}{shape=coordinate}{}}
            }
        }
    }
    \centering
\begin{forest}
    my tree style
    [Paletizador
    [Inicialização\\de sistema
    [Sensor X]
    [Acção Y]
    ]
    [Sacos
    [
    [
    [Linha/Coluna
    [Garra]
    [Rodar Garra]
    [Acção Y2]
    ]
    [Euro Pallet]
    [{Disposição $xyz$}
    [{$x=?$}]
    [{$y=?$}]
    [{$z=?$}]
    ]
    ]
    ]
    ]
    [Sistema de despacho
    [Sensor de peso\\/contador]
    [Tapete rolante\\de saída]
    ]
    ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the relation between the code you post and the screen shot you show (other than both are trees)? The code gives rise to something where there are no folder-type nodes.

Comment: @Easy request upvote the answer if you found it useful by clicking on the upwards triangle on the left side of the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The `l sep` adjusts the vertical gap -- the `s sep` adjusts the horizontal gap -- gaps can be adjusted globally in the style set by you in the beginning or they can be set for individual levels

I have done it for one individual level -- `l sep= 10mm, s sep=20mm` -- I am sure you will experiment further

A short and concise pdf is located [here](http://ctan.imsc.res.in/info/forest-quickstart/forest-quickstart.pdf).

You can specify absolute values for these parameters, or increase or decrease their default values as calculated by forest. This is 3 done either by multiplication (e.g. l*=3 multiplies the default by 3), or by addition or subtraction (e.g. l+=3mm adds 3mm to the default, l-=3mm subtracts 3mm).

These parameters can be applied globally, to the entire tree, as follows:

### Example

```tex
    \begin{forest}
    for tree={s sep=10mm, inner sep=0, l=0}
    
    [CP
    [C]
    [IP
    [I]
    [VP [V] [NP]]
    ]
    ]
    \end{forest}
```

### The MWE

```tex
    \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{forest}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usetikzlibrary{shadows}
    \begin{document}
        \tikzset{
            my node style/.style={
                font=\small,
                top color=white,
                bottom color=blue!25,
                rectangle,
                rounded corners,
                minimum size=6mm,
                draw=blue!75,
                very thick,
                drop shadow,
                align=center,
            }
        }
        \forestset{
            my tree style/.style={
                for tree={
                    parent anchor=south,
                    child anchor=north,
                    l sep+=5pt,
                    my node style,
                    edge={draw=blue!50, thick},
                    edge path={
                        \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-7.5pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
                    },
                    if n children=3{
                        for children={
                            if n=2{calign with current}{}
                        }
                    }{},
                    delay={if content={}{shape=coordinate}{}}
                }
            }
        }
        \centering
    \begin{forest}
        my tree style
        [Paletizador,s sep=20mm, l sep =10mm  %<--------change made here
        [Inicialização\\de sistema
        [Sensor X]
        [Acção Y]
        ]
        [Sacos
        [
        [
        [Linha/Coluna
        [Garra]
        [Rodar Garra]
        [Acção Y2]
        ]
        [Euro Pallet]
        [{Disposição $xyz$}
        [{$x=?$}]
        [{$y=?$}]
        [{$z=?$}]
        ]
        ]
        ]
        ]
        [Sistema de despacho
        [Sensor de peso\\/contador]
        [Tapete rolante\\de saída]
        ]
        ]
    \end{forest}
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Dear js bibra,  Thank you so much. Best regards.

Comment: I vote for this help as well. Thank you.